# Atiyah Macdonald Chapter 10. Is a topological group which is isomorphic to a complete topological group also complete?

Tags: commutative-algebra, topological-groups

I read Atiyah Macdonald Introduction to commutative algebra.
In this book at p.105, the author says

> If $\phi : G \rightarrow \hat{G}$ is an isomorphism we shall say that $G$ is a *complete*.

I think this $\phi$ is defined as $x \mapsto [\{x\}_{n=1}^{\infty}]$. $[\{x\}_{n=1}^{\infty}]$ is an element in $\hat{G}$ and expresses an equivalence class of cauchy sequences which is equivalent to the constant sequence $\{x\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
In this book, a cauchy sequence and its equivalent class in topological group is defined as the following.

> A *Cauchy sequence* in $G$ is defined to be a sequence $(x_{\nu})$ of elements of $G$ such that , for any neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there exists an integer $s(U)$ with the property that $x_{\mu}-x_{\nu} \in U$ for all $\mu , \nu \geq s(U)$.
>
> Two Cauchy sequences are *equivalent* if $x_{\mu} - x_{\nu} \rightarrow 0$ in $G$.

The author says, in p.105,

> Thus (10.5) asserts that the completion of $G$ is complete.

However, we can just say $\hat{\hat{G}}$ is isomorphic (as a topological group) to $\hat{G}$ in (10.5). I do not know $\phi : \hat{G} \rightarrow \hat{\hat{G}}$ is an isomophism.

And, in (10.5), I think this book may use the following fact.

> If two topological spaces $G$, $H$ are isomorphic each other, $\hat{G}$ and $\hat{H}$ are also isomorphic each other.

This may be true in topological group.
But in general topology, I know this is NOT true.For example $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. That is because they are isomorphic but the completion of the former is $[0,1]$, the latter is $\mathbb{R}$. They are not isomorphic as topology.

Therefore if there exists two topological group $G$ and $H$ such that $G \cong H$ (as topological group) and $G$ is complete but $H$ is not, we can get $\hat{H} \cong \hat{G} \cong G \cong H$ as topological group.
So the $H$ is a topological group which is not complete but isomorphic to its completion $\hat{H}$.

Comment: You should define carefully what an isomorphism of topological groups is. This might clarify some things. This is related to your example of the open interval and the real line. These two are homeomorphic, but they are not isometric with the usual metrics, and the completion operation uses the metric, and not just the topology. It is in fact true that isometric metric space have isometric completions.